# Flutter Client Subscription to Spring Boot Websocket Server

Tags: spring, flutter, dart, websocket, spring-websocket

Below is my Spring Boot Code for scheduling messages to its connected clients.
But my FLUTTER application is not able to receive the the pushed messages from the websocket server.

```
@Service
public class GreetingService {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;
    private static final String WS_MESSAGE_TRANSFER_DESTINATION = "/topic/greetings";
    private List<String> userNames = new ArrayList<>();

    GreetingService(SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate) {
        this.simpMessagingTemplate = simpMessagingTemplate;
    }

    public void sendMessages() {
        for (String userName : userNames) {
            simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userName, WS_MESSAGE_TRANSFER_DESTINATION,
                    "Hallo " + userName + " at " + new Date().toString());
        }
    }

    public void addUserName(String username) {
        userNames.add(username);
    }
    
}
```

Flutter Code :-

```
var channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://1f470ad1bdc8.ngrok.io/ws");
    channel.stream.listen((message) {
      channel.sink.add("received!");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a Spring Configuration class for initializing the subscription paths.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WSocketBrokerConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

}
```